# Python Memory usage doesnt drop

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, twisted, perspective-broker

I am writing a twisted PB application that seems to use a very large amount of memory that never seems to get released when the user disconnects.

I have a pb.Root object that clients connect to and invoke a remote method that returns a pb.Referenceable object this object reads a large amount of information into memory (about 2GBs worth of data) when it is created to speed up the actions. This object, along with some other information about the client is inserted into a list.

When the client disconnects from the server, I invoke some clean up actions on this object to remove references to the cache object that is being stored. The chunkCache is the dict that i am storing the data in.

```
def disconnected(self):
    self.connected = False
    self.chunkCache = None
    self.cur.close()
```

Once the Client has disconnected the memory usage according to top never drops it still says 2Gb.

Should I be worried about this or will the allocated memory get released when its needed, or if not any ideas how I can release this memory? It is created when the object is created and not passed anywhere else.

Inside that object I do have one deferToThread call, could this be stopping the item being released?

I'm using python 2.7 on Linux.

UPDATE:

Im confused, I have just added custom `__del__` methods to my object and put a print statement in there  and they are being deleted, so why does the memory usage never drop?

Thanks

Dean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python - memory not being given back to kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957539/python-memory-not-being-given-back-to-kernel)

Answer (score 3):

On most current OSes, allocation of dynamic memory happens on what is often called the heap (not to be confused with the data structure of the same name), which is essentially just a contiguous region that starts at some base address and extends to the base address plus the current size of the heap. Processes start out with a small heap - typically just a few pages - and it grows as needed by extending the segment upwards in units of positive integer multiples of the system page size. Within that space, the allocation/deallocation create smaller chunks of memory to satisfy the needs of the program, along with whatever metadata the allocator needs to track what memory is allocated and what isn't. These smaller pieces of memory may be deallocated over time, leaving the heap segment essentially empty, but unless it's specifically coded, the heap segment is rarely if ever shrunk. As a result, a long-running process will tend to appear to have a heap segment that is as large as it's peak usage has been. The pages that were in use but aren't any more will tend to be moved off to swap if physical memory needs to be freed up for other processes, but the process image still appears to be "large", and generally won't shrink without being restarted. There are ways around that using other memory allocation mechanisms (e.g. mapping a temporary file for memory space and unmapping and removing it when done), but the program needs to be specifically coded to do so. Applications written in C or C++ that use the standard library allocation routines (`malloc`/`free` or `new`/`delete`, respectively), including the Python compiler/interpreter, will tend to exhibit the above behavior.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, and seems to mimic the behaviour of my application. As when a client reconnects the memory usage only goes up my another 100Mb or so and goes down a little when the second client disconnects. When I do some diagnostics to calculate the size of all of the objects it comes out at about 400MB which is a lit more reasonable. So you think I'm safe to assume there isnt a problem with my app?