# Twisted PB Spawnprocess that contains a PB Referenceable

Tags: twisted, perspective-broker

I am writing a server App that consumes a lot of memory, I have an issue where python is not returning the memory back to the OS so over time my application consumes more and more memory. I have done lots of tests and have confirmed that the large objects I am using are being properly released, so its a python issue.

One work around I have found would be to do the memory heavy work in a separate process and then kill this process once Im finished. But the memory heavy operation happens all the time the clients are connected.

I wrote the server using a Twisted Perspective Broker to handle the client/server communications and it works fine. What I am trying to achieve is connecting to the server and once some authentication has taken place spawn a process which is alive all the time that user is connected and then to stop that process when the user disconnects, this should solve my memory issues.

I am trying to work out the best way to handle this process. I can use `reactor.spawnprocess` to run another process on connection, but I am unsure the best way to proxy the PB calls to this sub process,

Any advice you can offer would be excellent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Memory usage doesnt drop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999853/python-memory-usage-doesnt-drop)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate, The reason for the memory not dropping was answered in the other question. The way to get it to drop is to kill the process and restart, or to have a sub process, that is what I am asking in this question, how to get PB to create a sub process