# When is a variable released from memory?

Tags: python, memory

Say I define a function, which builds a list, and then prints the items of the list one by one (no practical use, just an example:

```
import os

def build_and_print():
    thingy = os.walk('some directory')
    for i in thingy:
        print i

if __name__ == '__main__:
    build_and_print()
```

If the `thingy` that is built is very large it could take up a lot of memory, at what point will it be released from memory?

Does python store the variable `thingy` until the script is finished running or until the function that builds/uses it is finished running?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: It will be ready to garbage collected as soon as name goes out of the scope - so just after function call. When it'll be garbage collected - probably as soon as possible, but you do not know in general.

Answer (score 1):

Once a Variable goes **out of scope**, it is collected by the garbage collector.

You can see the collector [code here.](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/gcmodule.c) Go to collect function, there comments explain the process well.

Comment: Yes and no. In this case yes, in general, no.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on that @Martijn?

Comment: Technically, once it is no longer referenced it is eligible for collection. If you return a closure from inside a function, it would be necessary to investigate exactly how the Python compiler treats unreferenced variables in the lexical scope to see if references are held for the lexical scope as a whole, or just the variables referenced.

Comment: @JoeSmart ...it is *eligible to be* collected. It might never happen, or not immediately at least.

Comment: @JoeSmart: Python uses *reference counting*. When the reference drops to 0 the object is removed from memory. Local names in a function are just references, these are cleared when the scope ends, but there could be *other* references to the object still.

Comment: @PeterWood: in CPython, absent circular references, it happens immediately.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so, to simplify (for my newbie programming mind) once there are no more references to a variable it is eligible for collection, which should happen pretty quickly so it won't hang around taking up resources?

Comment: @JoeSmart: check. But take into account your OS won't reclaim the memory immediately; after all,  process may require more memory again in a minute. But Python won't be using the memory for that object anymore.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Cool, that's all I need to know for what I'm writing. Just trying to predict if I'll hit a mem error due to a few large variables, but the first ones fall out of scope before new ones are creating. Monitoring memory usage it seems pretty constant. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The code you link to has *nothing* to do with how most object deletions work. That function is used to track circular references (stuff the garbage collection must actually track).

Comment: @JoeSmart: Bear in mind that when a Python object is freed its memory is returned to Python's memory arenas, it's not returned to the OS. Those memory arenas _may_ be released to the OS, but not necessarily. See [python - memory not being given back to kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11957539/4014959) and the link on that page: [Why doesn't Python release the memory when I delete a large object?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm).